# html div stops scrolling after being nested

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a webpage and I am trying to make a navbar with a scrollable element but whenever I try to nest the element on the left side it stops being scrollable

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#contentbg::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.display {
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;

  .align {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Side Script</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./Assets/Images/SideScript S.png">
    <script src="./Scripts/SearchHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="./articles.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="flex">
    <div style="width: 280px; height: 100vh; background: whitesmoke; position: relative; z-index: -1;">
        <div id="logoBlock" class="flex"
            style="flex-direction: column; position: relative; z-index: -1; background: white; width: 280px; height: 230px;">
        </div>

        <div class="display" style="position: relative; height: 300px; width: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
            <div style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi est molestias optio necessitatibus, nesciunt, amet architecto explicabo voluptate placeat adipisci ea cum doloribus quae reprehenderit, ipsum porro. Autem, necessitatibus ad?</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="align">
        <div id="contentbg" style="position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 100%; background: white;"></div>
        <div class="display" style="position: relative; height: 300px; width: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
            <div style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi est molestias optio necessitatibus, nesciunt, amet architecto explicabo voluptate placeat adipisci ea cum doloribus quae reprehenderit, ipsum porro. Autem, necessitatibus ad?</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In the nipped I pasted to stackoverflow it works but when you try to go full screen mode it stops again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `vh` property for height in the left side div, which is preventing it to be scrollable. I replaced the `vh` with `px` (also changed its value) and now it is scrollable.

Check following example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#contentbg::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(10px);
}

.display {
  border: solid red 1px;
  overflow: auto !important;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  .align {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Side Script</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="./Assets/Images/SideScript S.png">
  <script src="./Scripts/SearchHandler.js"></script>
  <script src="./articles.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="flex">
  <div style="width: 280px; height: 300px; background: whitesmoke; position: relative; z-index: -1;">
    <div id="logoBlock" class="flex" style="flex-direction: column; position: relative; z-index: -1; background: white; width: 280px; height: 230px;">
    </div>

    <div class="display" style="position: relative; height: 300px; width: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
      <div style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi est molestias optio necessitatibus, nesciunt, amet architecto explicabo voluptate placeat adipisci ea cum doloribus quae reprehenderit, ipsum porro. Autem, necessitatibus ad?</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="align">
    <div id="contentbg" style="position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 100%; background: white;"></div>
    <div class="display" style="position: relative; height: 300px; width: 100px; overflow: scroll;">
      <div style="height: 30px; width: 100px;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi est molestias optio necessitatibus, nesciunt, amet architecto explicabo voluptate placeat adipisci ea cum doloribus quae reprehenderit, ipsum porro. Autem, necessitatibus ad?</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```